# Installing dual fluorescent tube ballast electrical

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I had removed a couple years ago a double fluorescent round tube light fixture. I want to install it back but am unsure which cables connect to the wall socket. I am guessing the white neutral with any of the left white cables and the black with the short lonely black cable on the left of the ballast on the picture.

[image: Light fixture back]
[image: Light fixture back closeup]

Please correct me if am wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white and black wires emerging from the left side of the ballast are the neutral and hot, respectively.   Perhaps the poor condition and burn marks on the ballast label should deter you from re-installing this?